# Google Sheets function to divide two arrays and return the lowest number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I manufacture products and the challenge is I need to work out in a Google Sheets spreadsheet how many of each of my recipes (flower bouquets in this case) I can make with the current stock on hand.

I have a dataset which shows my stock qty (number of each flower) in column B, then I have my products across the top of the page in a row. Product 1 is shown in column C, Product 2 in D etc....

Here is the example.
[Divide two arrays and return lowest number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdteS.png)

As I have hundreds of products and also hundreds of different component parts I need to work out what formula can essentially divide these two arrays and return to me the MIN or lowest number, this is essentially the number of bouquets I can make.

Thanks in advance

I have tried experimenting with SUMPRODUCT as I wondered if you can use this for division as well as multiplication, but I cannot seem to fathom this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula in `C11`:

```
= ROUNDDOWN(MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR( $B2:$B9/C2:C9 ))))
```

You can then drag the formula to `D11`.

Alternatively you can use the new `bycol` function to calculate the complete array:

```
= BYCOL(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR( B2:B9/C2:D9 )), LAMBDA(x, ROUNDDOWN(MIN(x))))
```